# What is the most reliable way to get current AD domain-join information? (DsRoleGetPrimaryDomainInformation,?)

Tags: c#, winapi, active-directory, registry, azure-active-directory

With the advent of Azure AD domain join, several of the existing answers are likely outdated or incomplete.

What is the most accurate/reliable way to obtain the current AD domain status, and do it in such a way that I can tell if it's Azure AD, On Premise AD, or any other possible design (native UNIX Kerberos?)

Some of the keys I've found include:

- HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\
- HKLM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Domain
- Configuration/Policies/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Workplace Join

Aside from calling the win32 API, DsRoleGetPrimaryDomainInformation, I may also inspect the registry.

- What is the most reliable method to get the primary domain join status?

Any additional information that relates to verifying the computer trust, connectivity "quality" to the domain controllers would be useful.

Comment: Have you tried Microsoft Graph? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be two questions here:

1. Find out if the computer is joined to a domain, and
2. Find out what kind of domain it is.

I have a solution for the first question anyway. You tagged `c#`, so if that's what you're using, you can use [`Domain.GetComputerDomain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain.getcomputerdomain). Put it in a `try`/`catch` block since if the computer is not joined to a domain, it will throw an `ActiveDirectoryObjectNotFoundException` exception.

But if it is joined to a domain, you get back a [`Domain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain) object. That will give you some information about the domain, like the [`DomainMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domainmode). I don't have access to a machine joined to an AzureAD domain, so I don't know what that information looks like in that case, but it might be different.

Otherwise, for deeper information about the domain, you will likely need to use the `Name` of the domain and try to read more information from the domain itself.